# Push element in an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an empty array:

```
const timeArray = []
const a = new Date(startTime_minTime)
const b = new Date(startTime_maxTime)
const disabledValueStart = new Date(maxStart)

// where startTime_minTime and startTime_maxTime are only two dates (date and time) and maxStart is the last value

Date.prototype.addHours = function (h) {
  this.setTime(this.getTime() + h * 60 * 30 * 1000)
  return this
}

//  Now I'm trying to do a while to populate the array 
while (a <= b) {
  timeArray.push(a)
  if (a !== disabledValueStart) {
    a.addHours(1)
  }
}
```

The problem is that my array has only the last value
repeated for the number of elements that should populate it, how do I add one element at a time, so that I have them all at the end and not just the same repeated value?

Comment: You're pushing the exact same object on each iteration

Comment: So it not enter in the the if and add hour to variable 'a' ?

Comment: That depends on the values of `a`, `b`, and `disabledValueStart`.

Comment: What does this code have to do with React/React Native?

Comment: I should populate the array with date except for disabledValueStart

Comment: Are `timeArray` and `startTimeArray` supposed to be the same variable?

Comment: yes sorry my bad, i edit post

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the same date (`a`) to the array, over and over. Clone the date and push the clone. That way each item in the array is a different date.

Here is a working snippet. The key is `timeArray.push(new Date(a))`.

```js
const timeArray = []
const a = new Date()
const b = new Date(a.getTime()+60*60*24*1000)
const disabledValueStart = new Date(a.getTime()-60*60*24*1000)

Date.prototype.addHours = function (h) {
  this.setTime(this.getTime() + h * 60 * 30 * 1000)
  return this
}

while (a <= b) {
  timeArray.push(new Date(a)) // here is the important change
  if (a !== disabledValueStart) {
    a.addHours(1)
  }
}

console.log(timeArray)
```

Comment: Please don't just dump a load of code. _Explain_ what the problem was and _document_ what your code does to solve it.